# Jquery slide left right with button

Tags: jquery, html, slide

I am creating a simple jquery slide. When the user clicks on the button 1 div box will show form the right and one will hide form left.
Here is my code but in this when i click on the button all div's moves from right to left but none of them hide form left.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .row{
        max-height: 40px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: pink;
    }
    .col-md-4{
        border: 10px solid #eee;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">gh</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">gh</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">gh</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">gh</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">gh</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">gh</div>
</div>

<button>Click</button>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $('button').click(function(){
    $(".col-md-4").next().animate({width:'toggle'},2000);
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you intended (and not something I misunderstood)

Basically, the following fiddle makes that the `div` shown disapear sliding to the left when you click on the `button` and the following one shows up from the right.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwtogkja/)

Regards

Comment: Thanks man . I already fix the issue but i'm accepting your ans too.